# Pecl complies .so extensions for OSX built-in PHP and not MAMP

Tags: linux, php, mamp, pecl, sphinxsearch

I've installed the sphinx binaries and libraries and am now trying to install the PECL sphinx module.

My system is running OS X 10.6 with MAMP 1.8.2 installed. I try to install sphinx using the following command:

```
sudo pecl install sphinx
```

The PECL command outputs the following:

```
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

The versions above don't match the versions listed when doing a `phpinfo()`. It seems that PECL is trying to complie against the built-in version of PHP.

If I ignore the errors and continue the it will successfully compile and place the `sphinx.so` file in:

`/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sphinx.so`

when in fact it should be:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/`

I've tried copying the sphinx.so file to the MAMP extensions dir but when I restart apache PHP displays the following warning:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sphinx.so`

I think this is because MAMP is 32bit and the built-in PHP is 64bit so PECL complies for 64bit. I might be completely wrong but I did read this when I goggled on the topic.

Does anyone know how to get PECL to map to the MAMP version of PHP instead of the built-in version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the problem still exists: Here's a link and some additional information:
http://blog.achimbo.de/index.php/2010/05/03/installing-pecl-for-mamp/

Cheers,
achim